# c++ Problems with pushing structs onto a vector and then saving to an outputfile

Tags: c++, struct, ofstream, static-cast

I did away with the vector idea, and after a fair bit of faffing around managed to get the struct in and out of a file. I'm really enjoying the challenge of c++, so much to learn!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Account_query
{
public:
    char name[50];
    char number[50];
};

void AddRecord(Account_query* aq)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("Records.out", ios::app | ios::out | ios::binary);
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> aq->name;
    cout << "Enter account number: ";
    cin >> aq->number;
    fout.write( reinterpret_cast<const char *>( &(*aq) ), sizeof(Account_query) );
    fout.close();
}
void ShowRecord()
{
    Account_query aq;
    //std::memset(&aq, 0, sizeof(aq));
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("Records.out", ios::binary);
    if(!inf)
    {
        cout << "Problem opening"<<endl;
    }
    cout <<"####Data Out###"<<endl;
    while(!inf.eof())
    {
        inf.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(&aq.name), sizeof(Account_query::name));
        inf.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(&aq.number), sizeof(Account_query::number));
        cout << "Name is: " << aq.name << "Account is: " << aq.number <<endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    vector<Account_query> list;
    
    cout << "Welcome to Jizz Bank\n";
    cout << "Enter one of the following options then press enter\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "1) Add Record \n";
    cout << "2) Show Records \n";
    cout << "3) Search Record \n";
    cout << "4) Edit Record \n";
    cout << "5) Delete Record \n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    
    int x;
    cin >>x;
    
    Account_query a;
    Account_query *p = &a;
    
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:{
            
            AddRecord(p);//got the data for object now
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            ShowRecord();
            break;
        }
        default:{
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Previous entry below...
I'm trying to write a console program to learn c++.
In case 1 of the switch I'm dynamically creating a struct and then sending it to a function along with a reference to a vector.
The idea is to input some simple data to populate the struct, then to push this onto a vector and then write this to a file (binary).
The problem seems to be:

`fout.write(static_cast<char*> (*it), sizeof(Account_query));`

I get, Cannot cast from type 'Account_query' to pointer type 'char *' in Xcode.
I've tried reinterpret_cast amongst other things but that doesn't work either.
Would really appreciate any help,
LD.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Account_query
{
public:
    char name[50];
    char number[50];
};

void AddRecord(Account_query* aq, vector<Account_query>& list)
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("Records.bank", ios::binary | ios::out);
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> aq->name;
    cout << "Enter account number: ";
    cin >> aq->number;
    list.push_back(*aq);
    
    for (vector<Account_query>::iterator it=list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    {
        fout.write(static_cast<char*> (*it), sizeof(Account_query));
    }
    fout.close();
}
void ShowRecord()
{
   //TODO
   
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    vector<Account_query> list;
    
    cout << "Welcome to Jizz Bank\n";
    cout << "Enter one of the following options then press enter\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "1) Add Record \n";
    cout << "2) Show Records \n";
    cout << "3) Search Record \n";
    cout << "4) Edit Record \n";
    cout << "5) Delete Record \n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    
    int x;
    cin >>x;
    
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:{
            Account_query* a = new Account_query;
            AddRecord(a, list);//got the data for object now
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            cout<<"do nowt yet"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        default:{
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To write the raw data to a file, the `write` function requires a *pointer* to the first byte of the data to write. `*it` is an `Account_query` object, not a pointer. What have you read about pointers, and how to get pointers to objects?

Comment: `vector<Account_query>::iterator` i think you are using a very old book or tutorial... what's your source?

Comment: There's also another problem, and it also have to do with pointers... And that problem can be solved by *not* using pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make life difficult for yourself. Start by using `std::string`, and then just use the `operator<<` to put the strings in the file (and read from it). e.g.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct AccountQuery
{
    std::string name;
    std::string number;
};

AccountQuery AddRecord()
{
    AccountQuery aq;
    std::cout << "Enter name: ";
    std::cin >> aq.name;
    std::cout << "Enter account number: ";
    std::cin >> aq.number;
    {
        std::ofstream fout("Records.out", std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
        fout << aq.name << " " << aq.number << " "; // spaces for simple separation. 
    }
    return aq;
}
void ShowRecord()
{
    AccountQuery aq;
    std::ifstream fin("Records.out", std::ios::binary);
    if(!fin)
    {
        std::cerr << "Problem opening file.\n";
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "####Data Out###\n";
    while(fin >> aq.name && fin >> aq.number) {
        std::cout << "Name is: " << aq.name << ", Account is: " << aq.number << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout
       << "Welcome to Jizz Bank\n"
       << "Enter one of the following options then press enter\n"
       << "-----------------------------------\n"
       << "1) Add Record\n"
       << "2) Show Records\n"
       << "3) Search Record\n"
       << "4) Edit Record\n"
       << "5) Delete Record\n"
       << "6) Exit\n"
       << "-----------------------------------\n";
    
    bool loop = true;
    while(loop) {
        std::cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: {
                AddRecord();//return value unused?
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                ShowRecord();
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                loop = false;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                // nothing, could be omitted
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```